# How to display TextView using ToggleButton in Android

Tags: android, textview, togglebutton

I have a toggleButton with a textView. The idea is that when the "plus" image on the togglebutton is clicked, it will reveal the full textView.

At the moment, I can display Toasts correctly, as below:

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked())
                     DisplayToast("Toggle button is On");
                else
                  DisplayToast("Toggle button is Off");
              }


            });
          }
      private void DisplayToast(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

BUT I WANT TO INCORPORATE:

TextView tv = (TextView) Design.this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

After the "if" statement. But Android doesn't like it. How do I add the above statement (with a "else" showing same statement, but View.GONE ??

Comment: What do you mean by "Android doesn't like it"? Are you getting an error and if so, what is the error or is it just doing nothing? Please indicate exactly where you placed the code to set the visibility.

Comment: What's the problem just use if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked())
                     tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                  tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked())
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    });
}
```